# XeLaTex/LuaLaTex not changing font in beamer

Tags: xetex, luatex

I am trying to compile the following, but when I compile it, the beamer presentation still has the default font. I cannot figure out why

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path = ./ ,
UprightFont = Essays1743,
Extension = .ttf]{essays}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
```

Comment: as always on this site please extend your example to a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to help

Comment: Set the sans font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `beamer` uses the sans-serif font as the default font.  One way to override that is to load

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
```

or

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

That gives you back control of the font selection.  You should also set the sans-serif font. Some themes you load may select it anyway.